# Woocommerce searchable product custom field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, field

my products have two important codes which are the EAN-13 and its model number. I wrote the EAN-13 in the SKU and the products model number in a custom field. The SKU is perfectly searchable but the data is not.

Is there any way to make a product custom field searchable from the back-end office?

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When I was searching for almost similar problem I've found solution here https://dominykasgel.com/extend-search-custom-post-types-wordpress-admin/, here's my code for functions.php in child theme:

```
function extend_admin_search( $query ) {

$custom_fields = array(
    "_file_name",
);

if( ! is_admin() )
    return;

$search_term = $query->query_vars['s'];
$query->query_vars['s'] = '';
$query->set('_meta_or_title', $search_term);

if ( $search_term != '' ) {
    $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );

    foreach( $custom_fields as $custom_field ) {
        array_push( $meta_query, array(
            'key' => $custom_field,
            'value' => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ));
    }
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
};
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'extend_admin_search', 6, 2);

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $q )
{
if( $title = $q->get( '_meta_or_title' ) )
{
    add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', function( $sql ) use ( $title )
    {
        global $wpdb;

        // Only run once:
        static $nr = 0; 
        if( 0 != $nr++ ) return $sql;

        // Modified WHERE
        $sql['where'] = sprintf(
            " AND ( %s OR %s ) ",
            $wpdb->prepare( "{$wpdb->posts}.post_title like '%%%s%%'", $title),
            mb_substr( $sql['where'], 5, mb_strlen( $sql['where'] ) )
        );

        return $sql;
    }, 12, 1);
}
}, 12, 1);
```

DISCLAIMER: it was used a few years ago, so I can't be sure if it works fine for now.